How to make a docker container for Quasar?
I am new to Quasar. And I have recently created a Quasar app, how can I dockerise it?
The problem with my current setup is that the browser reloads non-stop.
I changed this in quasar.config.js:
const { configure } = require("quasar/wrappers");

module.exports = configure(function (/* ctx */) {
  return {
    // ...
    devServer: {
      open: false, // opens browser window automatically set to false
    },
    // ...
  }
}

development.Dockerfile:
FROM node:20-bookworm

RUN npm i -g @quasar/cli

CMD sh -c 'npm i && quasar dev -m ssr'

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  frontend:
    image: quasar
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: development.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
      - 9100:9100


You don't really seem to be using the image at all.  Can you run the quasar dev command on the host, without involving Docker at all?

Well, I want to use docker for the backend, and I think it may be convenient to run the frontend in docker as well. However, why do you think I shouldn't do it? @DavidMaze

This setup isn't "using Docker" in any interesting way.  You're running a Node interpreter against code that lives only on the host, but you've hidden Node itself inside a container so you can't directly run npm commands.

Well, I can run npm commands. For example: docker compose run frontend npm run build, or if the service is up: docker compose exec frontend npm run build, etc.
